# Navigate two leaflet maps

Tags: leaflet

I am looking for an example where there would be multiple map divs containing leaflet maps. When one is panned I want the other one to pan or zoom with it so they are always in sync.

Comment: Try this: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/creating-synchronized-view-of-two-maps.html or this https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Sync

Comment: I have seen this kind of question before. You should probably post this as an answer as it is a great link that many would love to discover.

Comment: @BritishSteel ok!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a blog post that shows how to sync two leaflet maps:

[Creating a synchronized view of two maps or images with Leaflet](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/creating-synchronized-view-of-two-maps.html)

Then, as per a question in the comments, a plugin that shows how to sync more than 2 leaflet maps:

[turban/Leaflet.Sync](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Sync)